# Create special dynamic select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to do the next thing but I don't know how to do this, I'll try to explain me

I have an  field generated by php code like this (Works)

```
<select id="profiles_select" name="profiles_select">                    
  <?php
  do {
  ?>
<option value="<?php echo strtoupper($system['profile']);?>">
<?php echo strtoupper($system['profile']);?></option>
<?php
} while($system = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)); //the "$r" it's the query
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($r);
  if($rows > 0) {
       mysql_data_seek($r, 0);
       $systemas = mysql_fetch_assoc($r); 
  }
?>
</select>
```

**The query**

```
<?php
$q="SELECT DISTINCT profile FROM sys_profiles";
$r=mysql_query($q,$ConecLocal) or die(mysql_error());;
$systemas=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$tsys=mysql_num_rows($r);
?>
```

**What I need?**

I need generate another  similar to first  generated by php code but, this time I need made a Query including the value of the first , something like this:

```
<?php
$value_select=$_GET['profiles_select'];
$q2="SELECT DISTINCT systems FROM sys_profiles where profile=$value_select";
$r2=mysql_query($q,$ConecLocal) or die(mysql_error());;
$profiles2=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$tsys=mysql_num_rows($r);
?>
```

Next of the query I need show in the another  the query result, something similar to the first select (generated by php), but do the query when the first  of the  it's selected

```
<select id="systems_select" name="system_select">                   
  <?php
  do {
  ?>
<option value="<?php echo strtoupper($system['systems']);?>">
<?php echo strtoupper($profiles2['systems']);?></option>
<?php
} while($profiles2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($r2)); //the "$r2" it's the another query
  $rows2 = mysql_num_rows($r2);
  if($rows2 > 0) {
       mysql_data_seek($r2, 0);
       $systemas = mysql_fetch_assoc($r2); 
  }
?>
</select>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Stop using the long depricated mysql extension!

Comment: If you want the second SELECT to depend on the user's selected value on the first one, you must use AJAX to populate the OPTION fields. Or, alternatively, if there are not too many values, send all the values and remove the incorrect ones. Again, you need an AJAX call, or the logic must be in your Javascript.

Comment: Stop wasting space mentioning mysql_* is deprecated. It was deprecated from version **5.5.0**, released **20 Jun 2013**, and there is min 3 years maintenance garuantee. Furthermore, you dont know what version of PHP the OP are using - in many cases people and servers using a PHP version _prior_ to 5.5.0 - so it is simply waste of space preaching "dont use..." over and over and over and ...

Comment: I'll search how I can do that with ajax, thanks for the help, and davidkonrad, I don't define which db system they will use, I just develop their needs.